# How do I multiply these two matrices together and then simplify the result into something that is manageable?

Tags: matrices

I want to multiply the following two matrices together, but whenever I do the basic operations for matrix multiplication, I get a ridiculously complex matrix for the result that is very unwieldy to work with.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on how I can better multiply/simplify these matrices so that I get something more meaningful to work with when I multiply them together?

Thank you.

Comment: You could pull out the $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ and $\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}$. That should leave you with simpler matrices right?

Comment: What do you mean by "pull out"? Do you mean substitute in a variable for both?

Comment: These look like rotation matrices. So their product is again a rotation matrix, which must be fairly simple. If you set $r^2 = u^2+v^2$, that will help a bit. Also, you can ignore the fourth row and fourth column.

Comment: Rahul, I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say. Could you please explain that in a bit more detail? Also, bubba, yes, they are rotation matrices. If I assume r^2 = u^2 + v^2, then how do I simplify sqrt(r^2 + w^2)? Thanks. By the way, how do I type all the fancy symbols like you guys do? Is there a markup help section on this site? Thanks.

Comment: @HartleySan: He's saying factor out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$ from each entry of $T_{xz}$ and factor out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}}$ from each entry of $T_{z}$.  Then, upon multiplication of the matrices, you have a constant multiplied by a simpler matrix to work with.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see that now. Thank you, afedder. I will try that out and see where it gets me. Thanks.